# psycopg2 - fastest way to insert rows to multiple tables?

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2

I am currently using this code:

```
while True:
    col_num = 0
    for table in table_names:
        cursor.execute("INSERT INTO public.{0} VALUES(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, 999999)".format(table))
        cursor.connection.commit()

        col_num += 1
    row_num += 1
```

And this is pretty slow. One of the problem I see is that its committing multiple times to account for each table. If I can commit for all tables in a single query, I think that would increase the performance. How should I go about this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can commit outside the loop:

```
for table in table_names:
    cursor.execute("INSERT INTO public.{0} VALUES(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, 999999)".format(table))

cursor.connection.commit()
```

However, there is a side effect. First columns (timestamps) will have different values when committed separately in contrast to the same value when committed together. This is because `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` gives the time of the start of transaction.